# TLS 1.0 is an insecure protocol in .net core 3.1 console app

Tags: asp.net-core, console-application, tls1.2

I have a console app that runs with no error on my system with windows 10.
on server with windows server 2016 or 2019 I have Security warning: the negotiated tls 1.0 is an insecure protocol...
as I understood, .net core versions support tls 1.2! so whats wrong?

How can I find out what part of my code cause this problem?

so far I think that this warning occurs when my app wants to connect to DB

[Security warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rldt6.jpg)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63451303/how-to-enable-tls-1-2-in-asp-net-core-3-1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable TLS 1.2 in Asp.Net Core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63451303/how-to-enable-tls-1-2-in-asp-net-core-3-1)