# It is not possible to launch a C# web application using the HTTPS protocol on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, https, localhost

I am trying to launch a web application from *Microsoft Docs Tutorial - Get started with Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core*.

*IIS Express Development Certificate* for localhost - Installed.

**If I run the application using Microsoft Internet Explorer - everything works fine.**

And if with Microsoft Edge, Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox - **NO**.

For example, Mozilla Firefox reports:

> Secure Connection Failed. An error occurred during a connection to localhost:44363. Peer using unsupported version of security protocol. Error code: SSL_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_VERSION. The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified. Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem. This website might not support the TLS 1.2 protocol, which is the minimum version supported by Firefox.

Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge - ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

The search for a solution in Google, Yandex, StackOverflow did not lead to anything. The proposed solutions did not help.

**P.S.**

*Windows 7 SP1 64x Home Premium (Updated). Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 (Updated). Web Application C# with .NET 5. Windows Internet Properties: SSL 2.0, SSL3.0, TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, TLS 1.2 - Checked.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the solution outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63451303/how-to-enable-tls-1-2-in-asp-net-core-3-1)?

Which basically suggests to try enabling TLS 1.2 in the registry for Windows 7. Always remember to backup the registry hive before attempting to modify the registry.